# Top left and bottom right ribbons

Tags: css, alignment, ribbon

I am trying to get a ribbon png on the top left and bottom right of a box, (refer to the picture below), but was unsuccessful.

That box has a background colour and it's going to have some text in it so the ribbons need to keep their position whenever the box stretches. This seems to be so easy to do so hope someone could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning to put two `div`s in with `top:0;left:0;` and `bottom:0;right:0;`.  Like this in your CSS:

```
#box{
    position:relative;
    /* your styles... */
}
#box:before,#box:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;height:50px;
}
#box:before{
    top:0;left:0;
    background:#0f0; /* you could put some kind of image here */
}
#box:after{
    bottom:0;right:0;
    background:#0f0; /* you could put some kind of image here */
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/7CAun/3/) for a working demo.

Comment: This answer is totally win...but I would change it to use pseudo elements and classes rather than id. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7CAun/2/

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I'll add the pseudo-classes to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning. It would be something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/389hQ/

```
.green-box {
  position: relative;
  /* other styles */
}

.green-box:before,
.green-box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;  /* ...or whatever */
  height: 50px; /* ...or whatever */
}

.green-box:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("wherever the ribbon image is") left top no-repeat;
}

.green-box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("wherever the ribbon image is") right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

This should work in IE8 and above + modern browsers. If you don't care about IE8 then you can use CSS transforms to rotate the same image instead of having two different images.

Comment: I'm testing it now. Thank you!

Comment: `.green-box:after` should be positioned at the bottom right and not top left. Just made the edit.

Comment: Just posted a fiddle. The red boxes are where your ribbons will be when you add the right bg image.

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work for me. I found my answer already thank you so much for your concern.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use position: fixed; via CSS